# print() prints only every second input

Tags: python, input

I'm new to python and I've been trying to make a little function to call upon when I need to filter an input from everything except regular letters. 
I've used SO for parts of the code, but I can't seem to understand why does it only print on every second try. 
Here's my code:

```
import re
i=1

def inputFilterText():
    inputRaw = input('input: ')
    inputFiltered = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', inputRaw)
    return inputFiltered

while i > 0:
    inputFilterText()
    print(inputFilterText())
```

And here's my output:

[image: output]

I'm not really sure what's going on, but I presume it's a logical error. I've only just started using Python so any help is appreciated.

PS
The 'while' is only there so it's easier to test, it can be omitted.

Comment: delete `inputFilterText()` line, you never print the return value from every other try (including the first)

Comment: Please include your code as formatted text in your question. Pictures of code (or other text) are not appropriate.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry

Comment: @Wombatz it was accidental, edited again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling inputFilterText twice. Once within the print() and once before.  This is causing the code to prompt for input twice before printing the second response.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even realize haha

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you make a call to the `inputFilterText` function twice. The first time the output is discarded. Causing input to be taken twice, but only showing a result once.

To fix it, remove the `inputFilterText()` line. An example of working code.

```
import re
i=1

def inputFilterText():
    inputRaw = input("input: ")
    inputFiltered = re.sub(""[^a-zA-Z]+, "", inputRaw)
    return inputFiltered

while i > 0:
    print(inputFilterText())
```

Also, in future please send code as raw text, rather than screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest using a variable here, you're not doing anything with the first filter call (this is why it's asking the first time) and the second one you're only printing.

```
while True:
    txt = inputFilterText()
    #do some stuff if needed
    print(txt)
```